# CLOSED Firebase cannot initializeApp()

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app was perfectly working before a week ago this error occurred. My credentials are also correct.

One thing I noticed is this `getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN accounts.google.com:443` what does this mean?

> FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN accounts.google.com:443\"."}

Comment: Does your connection is behind some kind of proxy or firewall?

Comment: @KarloA.López no not at all. Tho I already figured it out. It's related to the dns nameserver settings.